# Probablity_basics_Straight Flush

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that a ﬁve-card poker hand contains a straight ﬂush, that is, ﬁve cards of the same suit of consecutive kinds?

My Approach /Attempt -:

Number of Straight Flush Possible=$\binom{10}{1}*\binom{4}{1}*\binom{13}{5}$

$\binom{10}{1} \Rightarrow$ a straight can start with any of the $\left(A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ,10\right)$

$\binom{4}{1} \Rightarrow$ pick one of the 4 suits

$\binom{13}{5} \Rightarrow$ select 5 cards from the selected suit containing 13 cards.

P(Straight Flush)=$\left ( \binom{10}{1}*\binom{4}{1}*\binom{13}{5} \right )/\binom{52}{5}$

Am i correct?

Comment: Assume only low Straight allowed,i mean only (A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) allowed ,No (10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,A) allowed neither (10,J,Q,K,A)

Comment: Please choose informative and precise titles instead of vague ones. I showed you how to do so in your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

- The ace is also the 1, so there's only 9 start cards;
- Once you've picked your start card, you have no choice whatsoever in what the remaining cards are: if your straight starts with a 3, it must go 3 4 5 6 7.

Comment: There are 10 start cards because the ace can be high or low: A,2,3,4,5 is a straight but so is 10,J,Q,K,A. So there are 10*4=40 possible straight flushes.

Comment: This is assuming we count the royal flush -- 10 J Q K A all of the same suit -- separately.  If we don't, then there are once again 10 start cards.

Comment: actually 1 will not be in the set ! edited! assume that it is compulsary low ..only (A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) allowed!

Comment: You mean 9 start cards if we define straight flush to exclude royal flush.

Comment: 10 cards if we don't count the royal flush as separate, and 9 if we do.

Comment: then  am i wrong @DanUznanski if i enforce the constraints that straight must be lower straight,not upper or not royal!!!?

Comment: Okay now you've included the 10, so that part's fine.  The other bit, however, you haven't touched.

Comment: I selected the point  to start Staright  $\Rightarrow  \binom{10}{1}$ $\Rightarrow$ pick up 1 suite from 4 avaliable suite  $\binom{4}{1}$$\Rightarrow$ select 5 cards from that selected suite $\binom{13}{5}$

Comment: I don't really know about sets of cards and where that's going, but I agree with bof that there are 40 straight flushes (if ace can be low or high) and 36 straight flushes if ace is confined to only being low (or confined to being high only).